# expo react native android clicking screen under stack navigation error

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, expo

I made an Android App with react-native and expo, and I noticed very weird bug in my app. It is the bug that it is possible to click screen in the stack navigator which is under the current screen.

For example, let's say this is [Home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozbpw.jpg) in stack navigator.

If I push the third tab, which is written "컵", it pushes [stack screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2dv3.jpg) in the stack navigator.

After that, If I press [certain area of the screen(I marked on the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glZ3R.jpg), it goes to [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS7mB.jpg), which is the screen that goes when I press the [fourth tab in the home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozbpw.jpg) which is written "asdf".

My guess is that it happens because pressing screen under the current screen(sharing same stack navigation) is possible. Can anybody help please? ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

Same bug here. Occured with:

```
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.3"
```

Solved issue by downgrading to:

```
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.0"
```